# Markdown title for pdf

Tags: markdown

I am using Markdown for VS Code. I am trying to get a title to show up on the tab when I export my file to HTML and to PDF. I really am not sure how I need to go about it. I have tried changing my setting.json with a markdown-pdf for header template. Can someone give me a hand or help guide me to the answer, please?